# TFS 2012 - Web Access tab in the Control Panel is missing

Tags: tfs

I recently setup TFS 2012 Version 3 on a server and just licensed it. I noticed when I open the Web Portal it says 'Some features of Team Web Access are not visible to you'. So when I looked online about the error, people said to go to the Control Panel -> Web Access tab, but I do not have a web access tab. Any idea why? I do not have TFS 2012 Express, however I do have SQL Server Express, but I don't see why that would affect this. I am added to the TFS Admin Console group as well. Can someone please guide me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are some features on Web Access that are available to everybody (with a CAL), and some that are only available to VS Premium and up Licensees.  If you have VS Premium/Ultimate and want to turn on those additional features (which is what the message you mentioned is referring to), you need to go to the Web Access Control Panel and put people in the Standard vs Full groups.

You can configure the user access levels by going to the settings page (gear icon in upper-right), then navigating to the root Control Panel (using the breadcrumbs in upper left), then choosing Access Levels Tab.

[image]

Comment: I also don't have the 'access levels' tab.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error (missing tab) and finally could solve it: The user I've been using hadn't been a member of the "Team Foundation Administrators" group (only various other *Administrator-Groups).

Once I added it (using the TFS Server Admin Console - not possible via Web Frontend) at "Application Tier - Group Membership", the tab became visible and I could switch to full mode.

Comment: My login is added to the Administration Console Users within the Admin Console.