# Assign Backlog item to Feature

Tags: tfs

I am currently using the TFS express 2013 with update 4.
I logged in into the web portal of my TFS project where I would like to add some featues and backlog project items.

I have some trouble with displaying the backlog items under features. I have created a new feature `Resignation`, created a new backlog poject item `Add resignation button to employee` and created a link between the 2.

But in my overview I see still the following:

[image]

I would like to see it like here:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first screenshot is in the Queries tab, looking at the Results of the Assigned To Me Query.  The 2nd screenshot is in the Backlogs tab.

[image]

PS - TFS Express may not contain the Portfolio Management features that you're trying to get to.  I've never used TFS Express so not entirely sure which features are in there or not.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I get the following error hen I go to the backlog: TF400409: You do not have licensing rights to access this feature: Basic backlog and sprint planning tools

Comment: You need to add yourself to the "Full" Access group (see this SO answer for how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550881/tfs-2012-web-access-tab-in-the-control-panel-is-missing).  However, there is a possibility that this isn't possible in the Express SKU.